# How to run a default task in Capistrano 3?

Tags: capistrano, capistrano3

Due to the lack of documentation I resorted to reading the Capistrano 2 [hanbook](https://github.com/stefanooldeman/capistrano-handbook/wiki/Building-Blocks-Variables-&-Tasks) and came across 'default' task.

Example:

```
namespace :backup do

  task :default do
    web
    db
  end

  task :web, :roles => :web do
    puts "Backing Up Web Server"
  end

  task :db, :roles => :db do
    puts "Backing Up DB Server"
  end

end
```

The idea is that if I run `cap backup` it should execute the default task..which doesn't seem to work.

**My code modified to suit the above:**

```
namespace :status do

task :default do
        webserver
        db
end


desc "Check status of nginx on web server"
    task :webserver do
        on roles(:web) do |host|
            execute 'hostname'
            execute 'service nginx status'
        end
    end


desc "Check status of DB"
 task :database do
     on roles(:db) do |host|
        execute 'hostname'
        execute 'service postgresql status'
     end
 end


end
```

How do you run default tasks in Capistrano 3?

Answer (score 1):

create a task outside a namespace and name that task the same as your namespace. Define that this task depends on your :default task within the name space

```
namespace :status do
  task :default do
    puts "Hello Default-Task!"
  end

end 

task :status => "status:default"
```

as you are using Rake within Capistrano 3 you can use that Rake trick.

Comment: I followed your code but I get the following error: `NameError: undefined local variable or method `webserver' for main:Object`

Comment: Hi, I didnt copy all of your code so there is no task named "webserver" defined. You have to do that. Or best for testing purposes. Just replace the calls to "webserver" and "db" with a "puts 'hello world'"